# Dimension of stalks at points in a fibered product.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian, integral, separated scheme which is regular in codimension one. We are trying to show that $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ is regular in codimension one.

Using the fact that the codimension of a point is equal to the dimension of the stalk taken at that point, we are looking to classify all points of codimension one.

The first type Hartshorne mentions is described as follows:

A point $x \in X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ whose image $y \in X$ is of codimension one.

I guess the explanation for this is that then $x$ is the generic point of the fiber $\pi^{-1}(y)$.

1. Why is $x$ the generic point of the fiber $\pi^{-1}(y)$?
2. Why does $x$ being the generic point of this fiber imply that $\mathcal{O}_x$ has dimension one?

Comment: I don't understand your question but EGA IV Corollaire 6.1.4 or the results around it should be helpful. Also, for the question on regularity Proposition 6.5.3.